# Send data from SIM800 to a server

Tags: server, arduino, html, gsm, sim900

#### Can somebody help me?

I have problems sending data from a SIM800C to a website.

**The first problem is**, I uploaded the following code to Arduino (I use the Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE to send AT commands to the SIM800 and read the response).

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define TX 10
#define RX 11
#define t 2000

SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX, TX);
int k=0, aS=0, amS=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial); // Wait for Serial ready
  Serial.println("Intalizing...");
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(5000);
  mySerial.println("AT"); // Send the first AT command to auto set baud rate
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("You can type AT command and send to SIM800 by using Serial Monitor");
}

void loop() {
  k=0;
  aS=Serial.available();  // aS: The number of bytes available to read from the buff of Serial
  amS=mySerial.available(); // amS: The number of bytes available to read from the buff of mySerial
  while(aS>0) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
    k=1; aS--;
  }
  if (k==1) {
    mySerial.println();
  }
  while (amS>0) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    k=2; amS--;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Next**, I send the AT commands below one by one and viewed responses. All the AT commands and responses can be seen on the Serial Monitor.

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","m3-world"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","mms"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","mms"
AT+CSTT="m3-world","mms","mms"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://weatherstation.byethost3.com/"
AT+HTTPDATA=9,10000
value=YOU
AT+HTTPACTION=1
```

The last response below shows that the data (value=YOU) have been sent successfully.

```
OK
++HTTPACTION:1,200,839
```

I have created [a website](http://weatherstation.byethost3.com/) to read data with the GET method. **My problem** is nothing changes on the website. That means the website has not read the data sent from the SIM800 yet.

Comment: Why are you sending the data as POST parameters if you want them as GET?

Comment: Sorry. I got the same thing with GET method (AT+HTTPACTION=0)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is sending a POST request. If you would like to send a GET request with a name/value pair, it should be structured a little differently. Changing your example from above:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","m3-world"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","mms"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","mms"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://weatherstation.byethost3.com/?value=YOU"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
```

Note the name/value pair is in the URL now and `AT+HTTPACTION=1` is changed to `AT+HTTPACTION=0` to indicate GET instead of POST

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got this problem. My problem is my server blocked all IP access, so I change to another server. Every thing are all right.

Comment: This is the proper sequence for HTTP GET on a SIM800 in case anyone else finds themselves here. Just make sure your modem is registered with the gsm network first.